# Want to create a live search in codeigniter with AJAX , mongodb , Codeigniter by using my already created model

Tags: php, ajax, mongodb, codeigniter

> This is my model which fetches data from database and displays all data in a table

```
public function get_masteradmin_data($limit,$skip)

    {
        $mongo = new \MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');

        //$filter = ['full_name' => 'www'];
        $filter = [];
        $options =[
                    'projection' => [
                                    '_id' => 0,
                                    'full_name' => 1,
                                    'username' => 1,
                                    'designation'=> 1,
                                    'department'=> 1,
                                    'official_mobile_no'=> 1,
                                    'official_email_id'=> 1,
                                    'select_user_type'=> 1,
                                    'permission'=> 1,
                                    ],
                    'sort' => [
                                '_id' => -1
                            ],
                    'skip'   => $skip,
                    'limit'  => $limit,

        ];

            $query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);

            $result = $mongo->executeQuery('justrack_db.master_admin', $query); 


           $res = array();
            foreach($result as $r)
                { 
                    $res[] = $r;
                }
            return json_encode($res,true);
            //return $res;
    }
```

> This is my controller , where i get my data

```
public function get_masteradmin_data()
        {

            $this->load->model('AppconfigModel');

            $config =[
                'base_url' => base_url('Appconfig/master_admin'),
                'per_page' =>7,
                'total_rows' =>$this->AppconfigModel->get_no_of_doc(),
                'use_page_numbers' => TRUE,
            ];


            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;


            $result= $this->AppconfigModel->get_masteradmin_data($config['per_page'],$page);     
            echo ($result);


        }
```

> I want to add functionality of live data search by using my this model . where i am already getting data from database.
>
> This is my Ajax query for live data search , on the keyup function. I was not able to go ahead with my AJAX function. Please help in this

```
function ajaxSearch() {
            var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
            if (input_data.length === 0) {
                $('#suggestions').hide();
            } else {

                var post_data = {
                    'search_data': input_data,
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url:
```

Comment: Your ajax part is incomplete.Can you post complete code.